# HTML page Distorted on same browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I am facing a problem that: MY HTML,js,Bootstrap based View of my web project shows perfectly/fine on my Google Chrome browser i have not hard coded any screen size. But when I open this same project on other machines Google Chrome browser the UI/View is totally distorted and also my jS/jQuery functions stop functioning . How can I control this behavior.

I have my code below, my I guess it is more browser compatibility than code issue. Please advise.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Wallboard A</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>High ARPU - H+HVC</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<section class="the-table">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter row-eq-height">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Logged In Agents</span></em>
                <span><span>6232</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>On Calls</span></em>
                <span><span>456</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Agents In Ready</span></em>
                <span><span>1553</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Agents In Not Ready</span></em>
                <span><span>0</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Agents In Wrapup</span></em>
                <span><span>45</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Reserved Agents</span></em>
                <span><span>478</span></span>
            </div>
        </div><!--/row-->
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Calls Offered</span></em>
                <span><span>4566</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Calls Answered</span></em>
                <span><span>1388</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Calls Abandoned</span></em>
                <span><span>3874</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Calls In Queue</span></em>
                <span><span>0</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Longest Talk Duration</span></em>
                <span><span>00:45:55</span></span>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6">
                <em><span>Abandoned %</span></em>
                <span><span>50%</span></span>
            </div>
        </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/container-fluid-->
</section><!--/the-table-->

<section class="the-table wide">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <em class="large">Service Level %</em>
                <span class="large">79.0%</span>
                <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>
                <em>AHT (Sec)</em>
                <span>136</span>
                <em>ASA (Sec)</em>
                <span>32</span>
                <em>Max Time In Queue</em>
                <span>00:00:00</span>
            </div>
        </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/container-fluid-->
</section><!--/the-table-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're missing the key component which is the contents of `css/style.css`. You might want to make a [https://jsfiddle.net/] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: sometimes you use absolute url (i.e.: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) while on other you use local path (i.e: js/bootstrap.min.js)

Comment: gaetanoM@ I will deploy project on iis local system no Connectivity from internet. Even if i use local directory paths. Issue is still there

Comment: If i run code without internet connected. UI runs fine.